# Tabitem binding in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, build.gradle, android-databinding

Hy everybody ! :)

I need a custom layout in the tabbed activity (or fragment) tabitem.

First-> I defined this layout for the tabitem:
**tab_item_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_item_root_linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_item_name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Wink from"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_item_number_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:text="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Layout tags needed for the [Databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html).

Second-> defined a tablayout (in the fragment but i didn't attached this):
fragment_surf_base.xml (this is the fragment with tablayout)

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/surf_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem                
            android:id="@+id/tabItem1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/tab_item_layout" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem                
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/tab_item_layout" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem                
            android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/tab_item_layout" />

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

And i need for the tab item (with binding) in the java file with these codes:

1. Initilazie my binding class instance:

   ```
       binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_surf_base, container, false);
   ```
2. Now, this binding instance in using (return null !! but why ? ):

   binding.tabItem1; this is null but i don't know why ?
3. And i need the tabitem layout items (tab_item_name_text_view and tab_item_number_text_view) with the tab_item_layout binding class instance by the binding.tabItem1.bindingClassInstanceReturnedItem << - But i don't have :\

Any idea for this problem ? :\
Bye ! :)

(Sorry my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform data binding in fragment_surf_base.xml in order to get the binding as follows :

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="variableName"
            type="packagename.yourViewModel" />
    </data>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/surf_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem                
            android:id="@+id/tabItem1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/tab_item_layout" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem                
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/tab_item_layout" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem                
            android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/tab_item_layout" />

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: I know this. But i need the tabitem layout items binding.
Example: binding.tabitem1.nameTextView.setText("asdad").

Edit:
And the binding.tabItem1 is null
but i use the tablayout.getTabAt(0) this is not null but this is a tablayout.tab and that i don't know casting to tabitem or other.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. I know, I shouldn't have used `findViewById()` but haven't got any way around for this yet. If I get any I will update my answer.

```
View tabView = binding.surfTabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView();
TextView textView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.tab_item_name_text_view);
textView.setText("Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I did it:

```
    val tabView = binding.tabLayout.getTabAt(0)?.customView

    if (tabView != null){
        val tabBinding = DataBindingUtil.bind<ViewTabWithBadgeBinding>(tabReceived)
        tabBinding?.count = viewModel.tabBadgeCount
        tabBinding?.name = viewModel.tabName
    }
```

Where 'binding' is your fragment's / activity's root binding.